# ajax Post data missing with tinyMCE on Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, tinymce

I have a problem with my form when I try to submit with ajax. I am using Malsup Form plugin for Jquery but also using tinyMCE editor. When I submit the form and check the $_POST array, there is no data from the textarea. I have tried to use the triggerSave() function but to no avail. Everything is working well in IE.

```
// These options are common and will be used for many form submissions

    var options = {
        target: '#notice',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response
        dataType:'html',
        resetForm:true,
        beforeSubmit: function(){tinyMCE.triggerSave(false,true);
        },

        success:function(msg){
            $('#notice').html( msg)
            refresh(3)
        }
    };
   //prepare form
    $('#savetext').ajaxForm(options);
```

Comment: Can you get the value of other elements that aren't textareas?

Comment: I can get them and  can alert the contents of the text area with alert(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realised using beforeSerialise: instead of beforeSubmit: does the trick!

Comment: THANK YOU! I just spent at least an hour trying to get this work Ended up doing this: `var form_options = { target: '#result', beforeSerialize: showformSerialize, beforeSubmit: showformRequest, success: showformResponse, type: 'post'
}; function showformSerialize(){ tinyMCE.triggerSave(false,true);
}`